# Execute piece of java code before spring context initialization starts

Tags: java, spring

In my application,  spring config file imports are based on environment property like below

```
<import resource="classpath:/springcontext/text/dao_${environment}.xml" />
```

As we know spring configuation imports are resolved before bean (property-placeholder) creation.

But my requirment is to set the "environment"  as system property from java code since environment value is not constant , it has to be set based on some logic
before spring configuation imports are resolved
Can I somehow assists Spring in how to archive this.

Comment: Are you talking around a web application or standalong , also are you using java based config or xml based

Comment: thanks for reply . its web application and xml based config

Comment: That is why the interface `ApplicationContextInitializer` exists. Create an implementation of that, register it and be done. Also do you really need to do it in code... Why not simply set `spring.profiles.active` as an environment variable?

Comment: Also don't set it as system property from java from the `ApplicationContextInitializer` you can simply specify which profile is active

Answer (score 3):

As @M. Denium rightly pointed, you can use the Interface ApplicationContextInitializer to cater this need

From Spring Docs

> public interface ApplicationContextInitializer
>
> Callback interface for initializing a Spring
>   ConfigurableApplicationContext prior to being refreshed.
>
> Typically used within web applications that require some programmatic
>   initialization of the application context. For example, registering
>   property sources or activating profiles against the context's
>   environment. See ContextLoader and FrameworkServlet support for
>   declaring a "contextInitializerClasses" context-param and init-param,
>   respectively.